# Automatically send an email alert when outlook is closed

Tags: vba, outlook

I need to have outlook send me an email to let me know that the Outlook session has been closed. The code below doesn't work , but works at Application_Startup(). Any other suggestions on how to do it?

```
Private Sub Application_Quit()

Dim objMsg As MailItem 
Dim EmailSubject As String 
Dim SendTo As String 
Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
EmailSubject = "Outlook session Closing" 
SendTo = "xxxx@outlook.com" 

objMsg.To = SendTo 
objMsg.Subject = EmailSubject 
objMsg.Send 

End Sub
```

Comment: Which office are using?

Comment: @Om3r I'm using 2013

Answer (score 0):

Latest versions of Outlook do nto fire `Application.Quit` event. The only workaround is to track the open Explorer and Inspector windows and check when the last window is about to be closed. On startup, hook up the `Application.ActiveExplorer` window and also track the `Application.Explorers.NewExplorer` event. Same for the inspectors (`Application.Inspectors.NewInspector`). When `Explorer.Close` or `Inspector.Close` events fires, check the number of still open Explorers and Inspectors (`Application.Explorers.Count` and `Application.Inspectors.Count`). If there is only 1 window left, do what you need to do.